# Export all of Sharepoint 2010 data (list, webapp data, etc. )

Tags: 2010, excel, export, sql

I need to export all of Sharepoint 2010 data (list, webapp data, etc.) in to a easy to import file. Meaning I have "SiteName" with lists and webapp data, and I need all the information of that site in a file or in a new database. What is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to export SharePoint data is to use the Export-SPWeb PowerShell command: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

```
Export-SPWeb http://sharepoint -Path c:\export -NoFileCompression
```

Use the **NoFileCompression** parameter and it will generate a few XML files and a bunch of other files in the path you specify.

Look for the *manifest.xml* file and it will have everything you need to restore your data.

If you just want to export from SharePoint to import again in another server you can either move the database or do the export and then ran an **Import-SPWeb** command with your exported data.